# Replacement for the INMP401 Microphone

Tags: microphone, sparkfun

Sparkfun sell a [module](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9868) with the INMP401 module on ([Datasheet](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/obsolete-data-sheets/ADMP401.pdf)), it has a small amplifier circuit and I have been using it in a project.

I am creating my own PCB for this and I've just noticed that the module is obsolete and I can't seem to identify a replacement.

What would be a good replacement for this microphone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the [INMP504](https://www.invensense.com/products/analog/inmp504/) as a replacement for this, no issues at all, similar characteristics.

Comment: Looks cracking, thanks! I've sinced realised it uses too much power so will be using a ICS-40310 which has very tiny power consumption and the same specs sensitivity wise!